# Mysql Query, Get result in week s column,Kind Of Aging Bucket Report

Tags: mysql

I have a table let's us assume it has three column 1> emailid, 2> orderno, 3> date

```
    ========================================
orderno | emailid   |   date    |
=========================================
1   |asd@abc.com    |   2013-07-20|
-------------------------------------------
2   |asd@abc.com    |   2013-07-20|
-------------------------------------------
4   |asd@abc.com    |   2013-08-25|
-------------------------------------------
5   |xyz@abc.com    |   2013-07-23|
-------------------------------------------
6   |xyz@abc.com    |   2013-07-23|
-------------------------------------------
9   |xyz@abc.com    |   2013-08-26|
-------------------------------------------
11  |xyz@abc.com    |   2013-08-26|
-------------------------------------------
```

............................................
table contains above type of data.
means emailid is repeating, and date is also.You can assume that per row for each customer and no of order on particular day.

Now what i want

I want result like

```
    ===================================================
 emailid    |   2013-07-01  |2013-08-01|
====================================================
asd@abc.com |   2       |1     |
----------------------------------------------------
xyz@abc.com |   2       |2     |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried a lot of thing, by using if in select , union .sp.etc.
First i wrtie a sp, making a temp table for weeks, opening a cursor and insert into temp table by condition.
But it is not good b/c taking long time to execute.
When I am Using IF it is not working.
I can not write my query b/c table is not so  simple.

So I need a select query with IF , as there are in oracle for aging report.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

pivot table can resolve your prolbem

This is a tutorial on how to achieve this kind of uses cases:
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78